# What effects you have to have in mind during LEO satellites observations?

Tags: observational-astronomy, artificial-satellite, satellite

I am attempting to calibrate my setup for conducting survey-like satellite observations similar. The idea is that I have a wide-field camera that takes images at 5FPS. The camera is equipped with a trigger that triggers the exposure of 144ms exactly every 200ms, synchronized with GPS. The camera is static; it does not track any stars or satellites. With this setup, I can observe a larger portion of the LEO constellation. There are some LEO satellites, like Sentinel 3A, that have their precise ephemeris published. I try to use those to check the validity and precision of my setup - I have some problems here.

With astrometry.net, I have an astrometric solution for my images with RMSE ~ 3-5", satellites on my appear as streaks, streaks but I'm fairly confident in my ability to calculate the exact position of the beginning, center and end of the streak down to ~0.3px (which is 3" for my camera). I am using EFRA to calculate atmospheric refraction and light travel time. However, I am consistently unable to achieve results better than 1px (10 arcseconds). It appears that there is a time bias in my setup. Is there any other astronomical or physical effect that I am forgetting, which could potentially cause a delay of around 0.01 seconds in the satellite signal?